# A function that increases faster than $\ln(x)$ when $x$ is small and then slower than $\ln(x)$ when $x$ is big.

Tags: functions, asymptotics

As the title indicate:

I am looking for a function that increases faster than $\ln(x)$ when $x$ is small and then slower than $\ln(x)$ when $x$ is big.

Here is the fig:

[image]

The red curve is the $\log(x)$, and the green curve is the function I am looking for.

Comment: Do you want the green curve to have a vertical and a horizontal asymptote like the figure suggests?

Comment: @Hurkyl Ideally the green curve approaches 1 when x is infinity.

Comment: @Leo The error function is one such function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function. Although it is not an elementary function.

Comment: I think you should give more specifications: desired range, values and slopes at the ends of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $\sqrt{\log x\log{10}}$ ?

[image]

Actually, any function mapping $0$ to $0$ and $\log10$ to $\log10$ and such that $f(x)>x$ in between can be used to compose $f(\log x)$ like you want.

You can also use [Hermite cubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), giving you all freedom to adjust the slopes.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements "when x is small" and "when x is large" are a bit vague.

However, try the function:

$$f(x)=x^{\frac{a}{x}}$$

and adjust $a>1$ to fine-tune the function's descent. Try with $a\sim 5$.

[image]

Comment: I add a figure for the function u mentioned. However, it decreases after some x value. I need a increase function f(x) (when x>0).

Comment: @Leo: I thought you said (in above comment) that the green function "ideally" should approach 1, when $x\to\infty$.

Comment: This bears little resemblance with what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: The OP changed his mind, midway after some of the answers were given. His answer to Hurkyl: "Ideally the green curve approaches 1 when x is infinity.", etc. Then, below my answer: "However...I need a increase function $f(x)$ (when $x>0$).

Comment: I downvoted him.